# Recycler View is appearing behind customized toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

main_activity.xml //main activity where recycler view is implemented

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context="com.umairahmed.inventory.MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toobar" />


       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/recyeler_view"
           android:scrollbars="vertical">

       </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_items.xml // list of numbers appearing in cycler view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           >
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_number"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textSize="40sp"

            />

        <!--style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"-->

    </LinearLayout>
```

toobar.xml is my customized toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">
    <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I don't know how to make recycler view appears below my customized toolbar.

Comment: add android:layout_below @id:toolbar  in recylerview

Comment: Thanks for the help! really appreciate that! @Hasmukhkachhatiya

Comment: happy to help you welcome happy coding @Umair

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/recyeler_view"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_below= "@id:toolbar"/>
```